# Cant navigate to other Viewcontrollers from a commonViewController's tableview click

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a `commonViewController` to pop up on other viewcontrollers and the `commonViewController` has a `view` and a `tableview` inside it and also some other components. I have populated that view successfully on other viewcontroller pages, but the problem is; when iam trying to navigate to some other `viewcontroller` pages while iam clicking the `rows` in `commonViewController`'s tableview.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {

              EditProfileViewController *nextViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EPVController"];
               [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];

    }
}
```

I have tried both presentViewController and pushViewController but it is not navigating anywhere. What is the issue. Please help me.

Comment: nextViewController is not nil ?

Comment: @gottlieb yes it is nil. why it is?

Comment: how do you think it will present a nil viewcontroller ? I guess your self.storyboard is also nil, because if identifier would be nil it would crash.

Answer (score 1):

Get reference to your storyboard and load viewcontroller using identifier:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];

EditProfileViewController *nextViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EPVController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Check self.navigationController if it's not nil

Comment: Ok, it seems that your view controller is not embedded into a navigation controller.

Comment: how can i embed a navigation controller?

Comment: your rootviewcontroller is an instance of navigation controller ?